# Preferred way to import multiple modules from package

Tags: python

What is the best way to import when you need several modules from a package?

```
from PySide.QtGui import QGraphicsView, QAction, QKeySequence, QMenu, QCursor, QKeyEvent

view = QGraphicsView()
...
```

or

```
import PySide.QtGui

view = QtGui.QGraphicsView()
...
```

or even

```
import PySide

view = PySide.QtGui.QGraphicsView()
...
```

I understand that in most cases the second way has the best tradeoff between ambiguity and length in the code. But are there any other considerations like performance when importing larger packages?

Comment: The best for you is to check if its suit `pep8` commandments.

`sudo apt-get install pep8`

`pep8 yourpythonscript.py`

Watch the output and edit, for sure it while yell for exceeding 80 characters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I quote from the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#importing-from-a-package):

"there is nothing wrong with using `from Package import specific_submodule`! In fact, this is the recommended notation unless the importing module needs to use submodules with the same name from different packages."